# Qt memory leak and CPU overload when window inactive

Tags: c++, qt, memory-leaks

I have a Qt application that displays and updates a number of ui elements (labels, custom widgets, progress bars, and drawings using paintEvent). To set the updated numeric values, I use a

```
void slotUpdateUI()
{
  ui->label_stateX->setText( QString::number(worker->m_stateX,'f',2 )  );
  ui->customWidget->m_cur = (int) worker->m_val; // m_cur is used by the widget's paintEvent()

}
```

`slotUpdateUI()` as well as `update()` are periodically triggered using a `QTimer`:

```
QTimer* timer = new QTimer( this );
connect( timer, SIGNAL( timeout() ), this, SLOT( update() ) );
connect( timer, SIGNAL( timeout() ), this, SLOT( slotUpdateUI() ) );
timer->start( 100 );
```

The CPU load and Memory when running the application are approx. 60% and 67MB. (Without the worker running, it is 50% and 60MB, that's just for the UI). These numbers remain approx. the same as long as the window is active (in the foreground.)

But, when the window becomes inactive (e.g. by opening a browser or finder in the foreground), CPU load and memory increase rapidly, well above 100% and 100MB within 1min.

When I re-activate the window, the UI freezes for 2-3 seconds, then un-freezes and CPU load and memory drop back to their original values 50% and 60%.

This problem does not occur when I comment

```
// connect( timer, SIGNAL( timeout() ), this, SLOT( update() ) );
```

My questions are:

1. Why is the CPU load that high in the first place (50-60% just to update a UI with approx. 40 elements (mostly labels) ). Is this a usual number?
2. What is causing the CPU overload and memory leak ONLY when the window is inactive (in the background)?

I work on a 2014 macbook pro.

Thanks for any advice!

**========== ADDENDUM: ==========**

here is the full source code:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/c90fg15s97mg9nw/OcGui.zip?dl=0

screenshot:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/betvc4palha8jp1/OcGuiscreen.jpg?dl=0

I removed `slotUpdateUI()`, all custom widgets, and cleaned up the code to its bare minimum. All that is left is a static UI, and periodic calls of `update()`. The in-focus CPU load is approx. 50%. As soon as the window is out of focus, the percentage rises at about 2% per second. 
Another curiosity is that the initial in-focus percentage is linearly correlating with the UI-size (simply removing the empty right half will result in 20% less initial CPU load.)

I am building with CMake.

main.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

mainwindow.h:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QtGui>
#include <QtCore>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent* e);
    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *e);



signals:

public slots:

private slots:

};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QTimer* timer = new QTimer( this );
    connect( timer, SIGNAL( timeout() ), this, SLOT( update() ) );
    timer->start( 100 );
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}



void MainWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent* e)
{
//    QPainter painter(this);
}



void MainWindow::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *e)
{
    if(e->key() == Qt::Key_Escape || e->key() == Qt::Key_Q)
    {
        this->close();
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you do in your paintEvent() ? That code can make everything happen.

Comment: I removed all the custom widgets and commented `paintEvent()` in `mainwindow.cpp` to no avail. It seems that `update()` is accumulating data and cpu resources when `mainwindow` is not in focus. I circumvented the problem by only updating when the window is in focus using this code:
https://gist.github.com/01walid/2276009

I would still be curious to know why `update()` is causing these problems when `mainwindow` is not in focus.

Comment: Yes, that's interesting .. normally I think, Qt would merge or discard additional update() calls it can not handle right now. Is the increase of cpu time only true if the mainwindow if fully overlapped or also if partly overlapped and how if it is only out of focus but not overlapped (e.g. side by side  with an active browser).

Comment: Out of interest: What happens if switch the order of the connects ? And what if you call update() from the slotUpdateUI() method ?

Comment: You still have this high "inFocus CPU usage" of 60% ? To answer your question above: It is not normal .. with only labels you should barely have any significant usage. I'm working on a huge GUI with lots of elements being far more komplex than a label an being updated partly more often than every 100 ms. So something might be wrong with your code in first place. Do you mind posting a minimal working example ?

Comment: I appended the source code in the original post, and I reduced the code to its bare minimum, removed `slotUpdateUI()`. Still having around 50% in-focus CPU load, then growing if out-of-focus. This happens also when the window is only partly overlapped. Thanks

Comment: One more question befor I'll try your code later today .. why do you periodically update in first place ? Du you wish to animate something in the background of the ui ?

Comment: Works like a charm using Qt 5.2 on Linux. CPU usage never above 6% or so. No increase in memory usage. You may give another version of Qt5 a try.

Comment: To get a hint on where the problems originate from you could use valgrind with memcheck (Combined in Vakyrie GUI Tool). I get one seemingly unsignificant invalid memory read. Would be interesting whether you get some memory leakage messages. And try vallgrind with callgrind tool (only command line, http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cl-manual.html). That will tell you what functions calls eat up all the time. You may post the callgrind results. in Linux is the KCachgrind tool for nice visualization of the call tree.

Comment: I tried the latest version of Qt - 5.5.1. Same result. I will also experiment with linux and the suggested tools. Thank you @Aaron

Comment: I'm also having this problem on OSX with Qt 5.10: steadily growing memory and CPU usage when the app is inactive. I am driving UI refresh and logic via timers. The app freezes for a few seconds when it becomes active, and the memory drops to normal levels.